# How to create a Subdirectory with os.join.path in python?

Tags: python, subdirectory, os.path

So here is my issue:

```
 def get_datasheets(self, build_id):
        catalog = self._get_catalogue(build_id)
        paths = []
        for key, value in catalog.items():
            if "data_sheets" in value:
                if value["data_sheets"] is not None:
                    paths.append(value["data_sheets"]["data_sheet"])
                    
                    for path in paths:
                        media_url = "http://some_url.com:8000" + path
                        print(media_url)
                        # Parsing the url and extracting only the datasheet name
                        parsed_url = parse.urlsplit(media_url).path
                        datasheet_name = parsed_url.split("/")[-1]
                        response = requests.get(media_url)
                        datasheet_path = os.path.join(self._output_path, datasheet_name)
                        
                        with open(datasheet_path, 'wb') as file:
                            file.write(response.content)
```

I am trying to get the datasheet to be in a subfolder called datasheets, but the current implementation only allows me to get the datasheets in the ._output_path, which is the folder that I select.

What I really want is to  be able to have something like: **output_path_folder/datasheets_folder/datasheet_name.**

**UPDATE:** so basically this is a method that extracts datasheets from a website and saves them locally, some sort of download. I gets stored with some other files so I want to have a subdirectory inside of the main directory that would allow me to store the datasheets. Hope it makes sense now

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the standard python library pathlib for working with paths.

```py
from pathlib import Path

datasheet_path = Path(self._output_path) / "datasheets" / datasheet_name
datasheet_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

To fit your edit it would look something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def get_datasheets(self, build_id):
        catalog = self._get_catalogue(build_id)
        paths = []
        for key, value in catalog.items():
            if "data_sheets" in value:
                if value["data_sheets"] is not None:
                    paths.append(value["data_sheets"]["data_sheet"])

                    for path in paths:
                        media_url = "http://some_url.com:8000" + path
                        print(media_url)
                        # Parsing the url and extracting only the datasheet name
                        parsed_url = parse.urlsplit(media_url).path
                        datasheet_name = parsed_url.split("/")[-1]
                        response = requests.get(media_url)

                        datasheet_path = Path(self._output_path) / "datasheets" / datasheet_name
                        # takes the parent from the hole path and creates all directorys that are missing 
                        datasheet_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

                        with open(datasheet_path, 'wb') as file:
                            file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: I am getting an unresolved reference when I try this, what am I doing wrong? Should I have the datasheets_folder created somewhere else first? and if so, how?

Comment: I/We need more information to solve your problem. Provide more code, your error and explain what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I have edited the post, please have a look now and see if it makes more sense

Comment: That should work for your code, but the rest is hard to debug, because you are using other references i cant access.

Comment: yeah it's a whole big project and it would be almost impossible to reference it all here. I tried your edit but it still just writes the datasheets on the selected path together with other documents. I still appreciate you trying tho. I will use what you gave me and see what I can come up with

Comment: Basically you can select a folder to save the files but what I ultimately want is for a subfolder name datasheets to be created, which contain the datasheet files themselves, regarless of where I chose to store them

Comment: I think that all you need to do then is add an `/ "datasheets"` after the `Path(...)` call. Forget to include that in my edit.

Comment: Hell yeah man! Adding / "datasheets" before /datasheet_name did the job. Many thanks. Just edit your reply a little to include it. it should be 'datasheet_path = Path(self._output_path) / "datasheets"/ datasheet_name'.